# Error in PHP : "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, oop, compiler-errors

I have an error Trying to get property of non-object in `C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\class.php` on line 44
Here is my class:

```
class Parser {
       public $links = array(
            'infosecurity' => '',
            'programming' => '',
            'webdev' => '',
            'linux' => '',
            'algorithms' =>''
            );
        public $headers = array(
            'infosecurity' => '',
            'programming' => '',
            'webdev' => '',
            'linux' => '',
            'algorithms' =>''
            );
        public $texts = array(
            'infosecurity' => '',
            'programming' => '',
            'webdev' => '',
            'linux' => '',
            'algorithms' =>''
            );

       public function get_article_link($page_link, $tag, $type) {
        $html = get_curl($page_link);
        $dom = str_get_html($html);
        $article = $dom->find($tag);
        return $article[0]->$type.'<br>';  //line 44          
        }
        public function get_content($page_link, $tag, $type) {
        $html = get_curl($page_link);
        $dom = str_get_html($html);
        $article = $dom->find($tag);
        return  $article[0]->$type.'<br>';              
        }
    }
```

Here is a code part where I call the method:

```
 $title =  $Habr ->get_content($Habr->links["$key"], 'title', 'plaintext');    
        $str = strpos($title, "/");
        $title = substr($title, 0, $str);
        $Habr->headers[$key] = $title;            
        echo "<br><b>TITLE : </b><br>".$title."<br>";           
        $text = $Habr ->get_content($Habr->links[$key],'.post__text','plaintext');
        $Habr->texts[$key] = $text;
        echo "<b>TEXT OF PAGE:<br></b>".$Habr->texts[$key]."<br>";         
        }
```

But when I use string link when I call the function, for example

```
 $title =  $Habr ->get_content("HERE LINK", 'title', 'plaintext');
```

it works fine.
How can I solve this error?

Here is result of *var_dump($Habr->links);*

```
array(5) { ["infosecurity"]=> string(55) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/kaspersky/blog/348572/
" ["programming"]=> string(50) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/348510/
" ["webdev"]=> string(52) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/skyeng/blog/348606/
" ["linux"]=> string(51) "https://habrahabr.ru/company/flant/blog/348324/
" ["algorithms"]=> string(37) "https://habrahabr.ru/post/348530/
" }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a debugger and check the value of all inputs to your get_content call right before it is called using a breakpoint. If you don't have a debugger, add a logging function to write your vars to a log. You may find that one or more of them are uninitialized. That would cause your error.

Comment: forgot to add that var_dump($Habr->links) show me the array that i need. But, I do not know why I cant use it

Comment: Please dump an example of the array so we can see it.

Comment: Sorry not to be clear. Can we see the $Habr->links array that var_dump shows when you run the code?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you show the output of var_dump($Habr->links)? Put that line right before you call $Habr->get_content.

Comment: The output of var_dump at the very end of question

Comment: No, that is an example. Please provide the actual output, as I requested in my previous 3 comments. That will help to detect the issue.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, needed to refresh my page to see the additional output you provided. What is $key set to for that var_dump? If $key is set to 'infosecurity' you should get the url string value returned.

Comment: Func calls in foreach loop

Comment: Add echo $Habr->links->infosecurity after your var_dump. Also add echo $Habr->links['infosecurity'] after your var_dump. One of those should return the url string depending on the type of array.

Comment: echo $Habr->links['infosecurity']  return the link what i need. But when i use it as a parametr it is going to error...

Comment: Please add echo $page_link; as the first line inside the get_content function.

Comment: Also, echo $html; after the get_curl call.

Comment: echo $page_link returns the string that i need

Comment: ok, so your variable is getting into the get_content function. But what happens when it is used in the get_curl call? Please echo $html after the get_curl call.

Comment: If you are not going to finish this, can you at least reverse your downvote?